# find all lines that contains an email address

Tags: python, regex, email, line

I try to save all the lines from an file that contains an email adress.

Exemple, file.txt:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor email1@mail.com sit amet,
consectetur adipiscing elit
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore
et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam
email2@gmail.com quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat
non proident email3@yahoo.com
sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
```

From file.txt i want to save only the lines :

```
Lorem ipsum dolor email1@mail.com sit amet,
email2@gmail.com quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
non proident email3@yahoo.com
```

I tried something, but regex is giving me a big headache :(

```
import re


def saveresults(var):
    with open("email-lines.txt", 'a') as target:
        target.write(var+ '\n')
    target.close()
    print " line writed: ", var

file = "test.txt"

emaillines = [linie.rstrip('\n') for linie in open(file)]

for i in emaillines:
    a = re.findall(r"(^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,63}$)", i)
    print a
```

What i`m doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

Your regular expression starts with `^` (start-of-string anchor) and ends with `$` (end-of-string anchor), which means the email address must be the entire line, with nothing else on the line, for the regex to match. You're also using `[A-Z]` but not `a-z`, and you aren't using the case-insensitive flag, which means that lower-case letters in the email addresses won't work.

Change to:

```
pattern = re.compile(r"(?i)[\w.%+-]+@[a-z\d.-]+\.[a-z]{2,63}")
for i in lines:
    if pattern.search(i):
        print(i)
```

`(?i)` makes the regex case-insensitive, and a character set containing `[0-9A-Za-z_]` means those characters can all be replaced with `\w` in most situations.

Answer (score 0):

Using regular expressions, you can use something like this:

```
result = [] 
for line in emaillines:
    if re.search (r'[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,10}', line) is not None:
        result.append(line)
```

The problems with your regular expression were :

- `[A-Z]` matches only uppercase letters
- The caret at the beginning was wrong
- You were forcing the email to be at the end of the line with `$`

I also changed the power from {2, 63} to {2, 10}. You were allowing someone to put up to 63 letters after the dot. Maybe that was intentional though, change that back in that case.

Also, you could shorten the regular expression to:

```
r'[\w.%+-]+@[a-zA-Z\d.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,10}'
```